# How to count the number of matches in a matrix in Octave?

Tags: matrix, find, octave

I have a column matrix of integers like `[1;4;3;2;3]`.

How to count the number of 3's (there are two)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The number of threes is

```
sum([1;4;3;2;3] == 3)
```

Comment: Especially useful to me for learning to do classification problem in machine learning!